# spark-submit job log tracing

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am running spark jobs on yarn mode.
I am using spark-submit to run the jobs inside the Unix shell script.
I want to keep the spark-submit command logs on Unix folder in the log file.

I tried

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 2G --jars $spark_jars --class $spark_class  $main_jar |& tee -a ${log_file}
```

using tee command. Then I check the status of the above command as

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "===========SPARK JOB COMPLETED==================" |& tee -a ${log_file}
else
    echo "===========SPARK JOB FAILED=====================" |& tee -a ${log_file}
fi
```

but if spark job gets failed due to some issues or exceptions, $? do not catch the error correctly instead I get spark job completed.

Can anyone please suggest recommended way for handling this issue.

My requirement is to have spark logs along with Unix script logs in the file

Answer (score 0):

The best way to monitor status of the application is using yarn rest api.

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-operating-system/content/using_the_yarn_rest_apis_to_manage_applications.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_State_API

You could use yarn log command for logs or use the yarn api for the logs.

yarn logs -appOwner 'dr.who' -applicationId application_1409421698529_0012 | less